# Create form from XML Values and Tags

Tags: jquery, html, xml, forms

I've got a form that currently looks like this:

```
<form>
    ID <select type="text" name="ID" id="ID"></select><br/>
    sectionNumber<input type="text" name="Name" id="sectionNumber"><br/>
    area<input type="text" name="Area" id="Area"><br/>
    Name:  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"><br/>
    <label class="Code-label" for="code">HUC</label>
    <select class="select_code" id="code" name="code" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
      <option></option>
      <option>10010001</option>
      <option>10010002</option>
      <option>10020001</option>
      <option>10030101</option>
      <option>17010210</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <label class="county-label" for="County">County</label>
    <select class="select_county" id="County" name="County" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
     <option></option>
     <option>Beaverhead</option>
     <option>Big Horn</option>
     <option>Blaine</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Using the following Jquery I'm reading data from an XML file and populating the form.

```
$(function(){

    function renderData(xml,sections){
        sections.each(function () {
            var ID = $(this).find('ID').text();
            $('#ID').append("<option>" + ID + "</option>");
        });

        $('#ID').change(function () {
            var selectedIndex = $('#ID option').index($('#ID option:selected')),
                section = $(sections[selectedIndex]);

            $('#sectionNumber').val(section.find('sectionNumber').text());
            $('#Area').val(section.find('Area').text());
            $('#Name').val(section.find('Name').text());

            $('#code').val(section.find('code').text());
            $('#County').val(section.find('County').text());
        }).trigger('change');
    }

    $.get('test.xml').done(function (xml) {
      var $xml = $(xml);
      var sections = $xml.find('section');
      renderData(xml,sections);//  call renderdata function to render elements
     });

});
```

The XML Data is:

```
<XMLReview>
  <section>
    <ID></ID>
  </section>

  <section>
  <ID>MISSOURI-NUT</ID>
    <sectionNumber>773</sectionNumber>
    <Area>Upper Missouri</Area>
    <Name>Missouri River</Name>
    <code>10030101</code>
    <County>Beaverhead</County>
  </section>

  <section>
  <ID>FLAT-STILL-TPA-2013</ID>
    <sectionNumber>774</sectionNumber>
    <Area>Columbia</Area>
    <Name>Sheppard Creek</Name>
    <code>17010210</code>
    <County>Blaine</County>
  </section>
</XMLReview>
```

What I'd like to do is have the Jquery create the form lables, not just populate the data.

So each 'section' will have an `<ID>` but then the tag names may change and the data in each tag will be different.

Is there any way to read the XML and create the form fields, lables and populate them if data is available ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've added an example of how you could dynamically create the form fields and populate them.

Maybe this is helpful and you can update this code accordingly so that it fits your implementation.

Not sure if you always want the select boxes populated with the data from the xml, but you can change the code of course.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="theForm"></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sections;
    var selectedVal;
    var codes = [];
    var counties = [];
    var selectorCounty = "County";
    var selectorCode = "code";

    function updateFormFields() {
        selectedVal = $("#ID option:selected").val();
        resetForm();

        // Set the selected value in the select
        $("#ID").val(selectedVal);

        // Loop the sections and populate the form fields
        sections.each(function (index, value) {
            var id = $(value).find('ID');

            if (id && id.text() && id.text() === selectedVal) {

                var theForm = $("#theForm");
                var sectionNumber = $(value).find('sectionNumber');
                var area = $(value).find('Area');
                var name = $(value).find('Name');

                if (sectionNumber && sectionNumber.text()) {
                    theForm.append('<label for="sectionNumber">' + sectionNumber.selector + '</label>');
                    theForm.append('<input type="text" name="Name" id="sectionNumber" value="' + sectionNumber.text()+ '"><br/>');
                }
                if (area && area.text()) {
                    theForm.append('<label for="Area">' + area.selector + '</label>');
                    theForm.append('<input type="text" name="Area" id="Area" value="' + area.text() + '"><br/>');
                }
                if (name && name.text()) {
                    theForm.append('<label for="Name">' + name.selector + '</label>');
                    theForm.append('<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="' + name.text() + '"><br/>');
                }
                if (codes.length > 0) {
                    theForm.append('<label class="Code-label" for="code">' + selectorCode + '</label>');
                    theForm.append('<select class="select_code" id="code" name="code" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid"/><br/>');
                    populateCodes();
                }
                if (counties.length > 0) {
                    theForm.append('<label class="county-label" for="County">' + selectorCounty + '</label>');
                    theForm.append('<select class="select_county" id="County" name="County" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid"/><br/>');
                    populateCounties();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function resetForm() {

        // Remove the content from the form and add the change event.
        $("#theForm")
                .empty()
                .append('ID<select name="ID" id="ID"><option></option></select><br/>');
        $("#ID").change(updateFormFields);

        // Populate the ID select box
        sections.each(function (index, value) {
            var id = $(value).find('ID');
            if (id && id.text()) {
                $("#ID").append("<option>" + id.text() + "</option>");
            }
        });
    }

    function populateCodes() {
        var elmCode = $("#code");
        if (codes && elmCode.length > 0) {
            elmCode.append("<option></option>");
            $(codes).each(function (index, value) {
                elmCode.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
            });
        }
    }

    function populateCounties() {
        var elmCounty = $("#County");
        if (counties && elmCounty.length > 0) {
            elmCounty.append("<option></option>");
            $(counties).each(function (index, value) {
                elmCounty.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
            });
        }
    }

    function getCodesFromSection() {
        sections.each(function (index, value) {
            var code = $(value).find(selectorCode);
            if (code && code.text()) {
                codes.push(code.text());
            }
        });
    }

    function getCountiesFromSection() {
        sections.each(function (index, value) {
            var county = $(value).find(selectorCounty);
            if (county && county.text()) {
                counties.push(county.text());
            }
        });
    }

    // Run this at startup
    $(function(){
        function renderData(){
            getCodesFromSection();
            getCountiesFromSection();
            resetForm();
        }

        $.get('test.xml').done(function (xml) {
            sections = $(xml).find('section');
            renderData();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this and report back :)

Comment: @Rocket
Was this a useful answer to your question?